# VBA, Filter by user defined dates on another spreadsheet for import

Tags: excel, vba, user-input, autofilter

So I'm trying to get some filtered information from another spreadsheet. I want the user to be able to choose the date range as the task often has a variable date range. I get the user to enter the first and last date they want for the information then get them to choose the spreadsheet they want to take it from. However, when it applies the autofilter no results are displayed, unless I manually go into the filter to see what has been applied and click ok at which point it applies the filter correctly. I've only included the code for the autofilter part as the rest works.

```
Dim StartDate As String
Dim EndDate As String

    StartDate = InputBox("Enter Start Date for Bank File (dd/mm/yyyy)")

    EndDate = InputBox("Enter End Date for Bank File (dd/mm/yyyy)")

'User chooses file at this point and it opens

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & CDate(StartDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDate(EndDate)
    
    End With
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I've also tried

```
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date

Sheets(BankFile).Range("A:I").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate
```

and few different variations thereof, but they all spat out the same. No entries till I go into the filter and ok the filter that is already applied.

Comment: What is your windows short date format in `Settings->Time & Language -> Region` is it dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Just checked and the short date format is dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: try  `.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(CDate(StartDate)),             Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(CDate(EndDate))`